# load a .so file within a jar

Tags: java, android-studio, jar, android-ndk

I have a jar file containing .so and java files and I would like to load the native libraries (.so files) from my .class file.

```
\-libs
    \-myJar.jar
         \- armeabi
             \- libNativeFirst.so
             \- libNativeSecond.so
         \- sdk
             \- classWithNativeMethods.class
```

Here's how code for loading libraries look like in my class:

```
    static {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load libNativeFirst.so");

        System.load("C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\project\projectmodule\libs\myJar.jar\libNativeFirst.so");
        
        Log.i(TAG, "Loaded libNativeFirst.so");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
        Log.e(TAG, "WARNING: Could not load libNativeFirst.so");
        ule.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }

}
```

But i get UnsatisfiedLinkError from system.load:
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\project\projectmodule\libs\myJar.jar/libNativeFirst.so

How can i load a .so file within a jar?

Answer (score 2):

The native code loader do not know (yet) how to look inside jar files as it expects a plain file in the file system.

You must unpack your libraries to be able to use them.

Comment: how can i unpack the libraries?

Comment: Either during deployment or you can unzip them yourself.  Elbow grease may be required

Comment: I'm using nativeutils.loadlibraryfromjar now and it should do the job as you said. But I've included the .so files manually into the jarfile - thus getting unsatisfied link error. Is there any way to include .so files via gradle properly? refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205242/creating-jar-with-gradle-but-so-files-are-not-included-only-a-is

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to include .so files into my .jar file in intelliJ. I'm working with an android project and I've been told to use .aar - but my task is to deliver a .jar file.

Comment: Do you have a senior developer on your team you can ask about this?

Comment: Not right now, they are not here for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I’m in desperate need to make it work.

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with android. Read the jar as a zip file(or locate the resources on the classpath), and for each entry you are interested in copy the bytes to a physical file named correctly in your file system.  You can then load that.

Answer (score 1):

Build an [Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) (AAR) rather than a JAR and this will work automatically. The JAR format does not have any standardized way of packaging and using native libraries. AAR does.